# Insert new line in string when number with a dot appears in flutter

Tags: string, flutter, text, numbers, newline

I have different text's that look like the following:

> "1. do some whatever. 2. Whatever you do. 3. Idk.

I want to insert a new line before a number followed by a dot appears.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a String and want to manually insert new lines you can just use the `\n` character which is a new line.

"1. do some whatever.\n2. Whatever you do.\n3. Idk."

On the other hand, if you want to do it programmatically, you need to look a `RegExp`
Something like the following could fit your scenario, it check all number + dot and add a \n before it but not the first one.

```
String addNewLineBeforeNumber(String input) {
  return input.replaceAllMapped(
      RegExp(r'(?<!^)(\d+\.)'), (match) => '\n${match.group(0)}');
}
```